# GA ecommerce code issue

Tags: javascript, google-analytics

I have a ecommerce code where in i am only passing transaction ID and Quantity details. but this is not recorded in GA API..Below is the code.

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
var _gaq = _gaq || [];
_gaq.push(
['mainind._setAccount', 'UA-12345-1'],
['mainind._setDomainName', '.abcd.com'],
['mainind._setAllowHash', false],
['mainind._trackPageview'],
['mainind._trackPageLoadTime']
);

_gaq.push(['_addTrans',
    '136069322',    
    '',                 
    '',                 
    '',                 
    '',                 
    '',                 
    '',                 
    ''                  
]);
_gaq.push(['_addItem',
    '136069322',                        
    '',                                     
    '',                                     
    '',                                     
    '',                                     
    '4' 
]);

_gaq.push(['_trackTrans']); 

(function() {
var ga = document.createElement('script');
ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
ga.setAttribute('async', 'true');
document.documentElement.firstChild.appendChild(ga);
})();
```

Please help me out with this..

Thanks,
Ashok Verma

Comment: KD can you please help me out here?

Answer (score 1):

You have to call the _addTrans, _addItem and _trackTrans commands for the same tracker object defined via _setAccount ('mainind'):

```
  <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
var _gaq = _gaq || [];
_gaq.push(
['mainind._setAccount', 'UA-12345-1'],
['mainind._setDomainName', '.abcd.com'],
['mainind._setAllowHash', false],
['mainind._trackPageview'],
['mainind._trackPageLoadTime']
);

_gaq.push(['mainind._addTrans',
    '136069322',    
    '',                 
    '',                 
    '',                 
    '',                 
    '',                 
    '',                 
    ''                  
]);
_gaq.push(['mainind._addItem',
    '136069322',                        
    '',                                     
    '',                                     
    '',                                     
    '',                                     
    '4' 
]);

_gaq.push(['mainind._trackTrans']); 

(function() {
var ga = document.createElement('script');
ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
ga.setAttribute('async', 'true');
document.documentElement.firstChild.appendChild(ga);
})();
```

Also note that [_setAllowHash](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gajs/methods/gaJSApiDomainDirectory#_gat.GA_Tracker_._setAllowHash) and [_trackPageLoadTime](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gajs/methods/gaJSApiBasicConfiguration#_gat.GA_Tracker_._trackPageLoadTime) are deprecated and should be removed.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Will check this and let you know.